# Can I write programs for the LEGO RCX 2.0 in Java/C++?

Tags: mindstorms, programming, automation

Is there a library which makes it possible to write LEGO Mindstorms programs for RCX 2.0 in Java or C++? With the LEGO software it takes so much time to write good programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was looking into this just recently. There are libraries and also it seems there are other firmwares offering alternative operating systems you can embed on the Mindstorm.

For C++ you could try:

- [nxtOSEK](http://lejos-osek.sourceforge.net/) is an alternative OS offering a C++ api
- [BrickOS](http://brickos.sourceforge.net/) is an alternative OS with a C/C++ development environment
- [NXT++](http://nxtpp.clustur.com/) is a C++ lib for controlling the original Mindstorm with a C++ API (through BlueTooth or USB)

For java solutions might be:

- [leJOS](http://lejos.sourceforge.net/) an alternative OS with a JVM
- The [NXTComm Processing Library](http://jorgecardoso.eu/processing/NXTComm/)