# Can you program an RCX using the Mindstorms NXT 2.0 software?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming, rcx

I was asked to teach a robotics class and found several RCX bricks in storage.  Can I use these bricks with the Mindstorms NXT 2.0 software?  If not, what would be the software I would need to use the RCX bricks?

Answer (score 5):

No, the standard NXT-G software provided by LEGO will not allow you to program a RCX brick.

Outside of official software, your best bet is probably to use [NQC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nqc/) which is C-like; there's also [NXC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/) for the NXT which is similar.

There are a lot of others which have been discussed in the following questions: [Is there any other way to program the Lego Mindstorms NXT other than the provided software?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/679) and [Can I write programs for the LEGO RCX 2.0 in Java/C++?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/190).